# no main manifest attribute (But I have the manifest file in the jar)

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

note- I have solved this and will post the answer for the benefit of others.
And note that I did look at other answers to this error but they didn't cover what was going on here.

```
C:\blah>type a.java
class a { public static void main(String[] args) { } }
```

Compile it

```
C:\blah>javac a.java
```

List of files in blah

```
C:\blah>dir /s/b
C:\blah\a.class
C:\blah\a.java
C:\blah\manifest
```

my manifest file which I wrote in notepad

```
C:\blah>type manifest
Main-Class: a
C:\blah>
```

Creating the jar

```
C:\blah>jar cvfm asdf.jar manifest -C . .
added manifest
adding: a.class(in = 247) (out= 187)(deflated 24%)
adding: a.java(in = 56) (out= 55)(deflated 1%)
adding: manifest(in = 13) (out= 15)(deflated -15%)
```

Running the jar

```
C:\blah>java -jar asdf.jar
no main manifest attribute, in asdf.jar
```

I looked through other answers to the question, they suggested adding a manifest file

but the manifest file is in the jar

```
C:\blah>jar -tf asdf.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
a.class
a.java
manifest

C:\blah>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I wrote the manifest file in notepad, it didn't have a new line on the end. That was what caused the error.

Windows uses CRLF as a line separator, in contrast to Linux which uses LF as a line terminator. So, when I wrote that one line in Notepad, it didn't have a CRLF on the end.

But `java -jar jarfile.jar`  requires that the Manifest has a new line (in this case CRLF) at the end.  Mine had nothing at the end of the line.

```
C:\blah>type manifest
Main-Class: a
C:\blah>
```

creating the jar file

```
C:\blah>jar cvfm asdf.jar manifest -C . .
added manifest
adding: a.class(in = 247) (out= 187)(deflated 24%)
adding: a.java(in = 56) (out= 55)(deflated 1%)
adding: manifest(in = 13) (out= 15)(deflated -15%)
```

executing the jar

```
C:\blah>java -jar asdf.jar
no main manifest attribute, in asdf.jar
```

which fails as we'll see, because no new line on the end of the manifest file

Add the new line to the end of the manifest file. This can be done in notepad too

```
C:\blah>echo.>>manifest
```

contents of manifest file

```
C:\blah>type manifest
Main-Class: a
C:\blah>
```

Run the jar file

```
C:\blah>java -jar asdf.jar
no main manifest attribute, in asdf.jar
```

failed because was still the old jar file ;-)

Create the jar file.. since adding a new line to the manifest file

```
C:\blah>jar cvfm asdf.jar manifest -C . .
added manifest
adding: a.class(in = 247) (out= 187)(deflated 24%)
adding: a.java(in = 56) (out= 55)(deflated 1%)
adding: manifest(in = 15) (out= 17)(deflated -13%)
```

And it runs fine no errors

```
C:\blah>java -jar asdf.jar

C:\blah>
```